# Ktor - I generated a new project to try a bit but cannot import CIO engine

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, ktor

I'm trying Ktor for a project but the sample project generated by the Ktor plugin does not work.
There is a problem with the CIO engine import.

When I put `import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*` it says "Unresolve reference: cio"

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    ext.ktor_version = '1.4.0'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}

group 'com.archilog_rest'
version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.tomcat.EngineMain"

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx' }
}

dependencies {
    println(ktor_version)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tomcat:$ktor_version"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-sessions:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-gson:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-websockets:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:$ktor_version"
    testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version"
}
```

I don't really understand why it goes wrong since I did nearly nothing from the sample...

**Edit:**
After looking how to import CIO I noticed in my `build.gradle` it was

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"
```

instead of:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:$ktor_version"
```

Kinda weird but it works now

Comment: Could you build your project with ./gradlew clean build without making any new changes to the source code?

Comment: So you need to install a JDK "Gradle uses whatever JDK it finds in your path. Alternatively, you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the installation directory of the desired JDK." You can find the instructions here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-A740535E-9F97-448C-A141-B95BF1688E6F 
Then, try again to build the project

Comment: The compilation failed because of the unresolved reference

Comment: Usually gradle takes the jvm veriant when needed using metadata. Sometimes it doesn't work because of older gradles

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"` will definitely solve your problem.

I've faced the same problem today, but after reading your question, I found my mistake. Thanks.